# constructing graphs in Java

Tags: java, matlab, graph, plot, velocity

i need to plot velocity graph for my velocity vector data(x axis velocity x comp, y axis velocity y comp). there is  a quiver plot in matlab which does so, is it possible to some how draw such graphs in Java.
please some one can tell how to do it, it would be real help.

Comment: Hi, please checkout the last paragraph from *How do I ask questions here?* of the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You should name this post "Quiver Chart in Java Swing" and post a picture for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you want to construct a *chart*, not a *graph*.

Afaik, the most popular java charting frameworks are:

- [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)
- [Eclipse BIRT Charting Engine](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-BIRTChartEngine/index.html)

Comment: unable to find the needed type of graph. can you provide with some hints, how to procedd

Comment: Now that you know, that you're looking for a charting framework, have you considered to take a look a the various OS tools? http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting